# Using multiple domains to load tiles faster in Leafletjs (not subdomains)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to speed up the tile load times of my custom game map: `www.nwnevilparty.com`, I just happen to have another domain doing nothing `www.evilpartynwn.com`, which I'd like to use to help loading the tiles. Currently my host doesn't allow subdomains, so I am left with that.

This is where I am researching from: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer

---

What I have tried:

```js
// Original line
main = L.tileLayer('maps/barovia/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {noWrap: true, bounds: new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast),}).addTo(map);

// Modified line -- Why only nwnevilparty.com gets used for tiles?
main = L.tileLayer('http://{server}/maps/barovia/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {server: 'nwnevilparty.com' || 'evilpartynwn.com'}, {noWrap: true, bounds: new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast),}).addTo(map);
```

What am I doing wrong and why is my example not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, the `||` operator returns the left operand if it is *truthy*, otherwise the one on the right. Furthermore, it is executed where stated.

In your case: `'nwnevilparty.com' || 'evilpartynwn.com'` the left non empty string is truthy, hence it is always the result of the operation.

Furthermore in the Leaflet Tile Layer URL template, only the `s` placeholder has a special meaning for working around the browser simultaneous requests limitation per domain. Since in your case you use `server`, Leaflet does not try anything special with it, except replacing it by your constant string.

As per the doc for the `s` placeholder: (emphasis mine)

> `{s}` means one of the available subdomains (used sequentially to help with browser parallel requests per domain limitation; **subdomain** values are specified in options [...])

And the [`subdomains`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer-subdomains) option:

> Subdomains of the tile service. Can be passed in the form of one string (where each letter is a subdomain name) or an array of strings.

Therefore you should use:

```js
L.tileLayer('http://{s}/maps/barovia/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  subdomains: ['nwnevilparty.com', 'evilpartynwn.com'], // also note that it should not be on a separate options object
  noWrap: true,
  bounds: new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast)
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful, comprehensive explanation! It works :) I can see the website is also downloading tiles from the other domain now.

Comment: Is this method going to only use the second domain, if it fails to get requests from the first one? I also added an cdn to my first domain now, but I am using this subdomains code which you provided here. Suddenly I stopped seeing the second domain even being used (so I think that's a good thing and means the cdn is working)

Comment: "_Is this method going to only use the second domain, if it fails to get requests from the first one?_": no, this subdomains workaround does not have any error detection. However some people have implemented something for this use case, see [this PR](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.TileLayer.Fallback/pull/6) in my plugin Leaflet.TileLayer.Fallback